# Resolve automatic factory from named registration for generic type

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

1. Assume a simple interface:

   ```
   public interface ICommandHandler<T>
   {
       void Handle(T command);
   }
   ```
2. Assume several implementations for different concrete `T`s like:

   ```
   public class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<FooCommand> { /*...*/ }
   ```
3. Assume a generic factory implementation of that interface:

   ```
   public class FactoryCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T>
   {
       public FactoryCommandHandler(Func<ICommandHandler<T>> factory) { /*...*/ }
       /*...*/
   }
   ```

Now, I want to register the factory handler from *3* to be the instance that is resolved when an `ICommandHandler<T>` is resolved.
My problem is that I fail to correctly register the other implementations so a factory for them can be resolved.

Here is what I tried:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
       .Named("concreteCommandHandler", typeof(ICommandHandler<>));


builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FactoryCommandHandler<>)
       .WithParameter(
             (p, c) => true,
             (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed("concreteCommandHandler", p.ParameterType))
       .As(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

However, this fails, because there is no named `Func<ICommandHandler<SomeConcreteCommand>>` registered. Autofac seems to be unable to automatically create a factory in this case, [which it normally supports](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories).

How to fix the registration and achieve my goal?

Comment: What is the implementation of the "FooCommand" object? Does it have a parent? If it does then you can try registering by amending "public class FactoryCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T : [parentclassname]"

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: It has no base class. And I don't see how the generic type contraint you suggest changes anything.

Comment: Applying a constraint tells the compiler that the objects of T can only be of a concrete type and it should be able to register where as without the constraint the compiler don't know what is T.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: I know what a type constraint does. My question has nothing to do with the compiler. It is a question about the API of Autofac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `RegisterAssemblyTypes` in this instance - it [doesn't fully handle](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=302) generic registrations the way you need to do it (you need to explicitly register each concrete command handler against it's implemented interface, including the generic type of that interface).

You can use the following as your registration instead:

```
assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => builder.RegisterType(t)
        .Named("concreteCommandHandler", typeof (ICommandHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(t.GetInterfaces()[0].GenericTypeArguments[0])
    ));

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FactoryCommandHandler<>)
   .WithParameter(
         (p, c) => true,
         (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed("concreteCommandHandler", p.ParameterType))
   .As(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

This will successfully let you do something like this, returning the generic factory with the named command as the constructor parameter:

```
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>().Handle(new FooCommand());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found out myself that the RegisterAssemblyTypes is the problem after writing my own `IRegistrationSource`... I hadn't yet figured out how to do it instead, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Tested and accept. Thanks again! I improved the code you outlined a bit, please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17068231/572644).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to plug [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) here, but I couldn't help noticing that you're struggling with something that is child's play in Simple Injector. In Simple Injector you can do what you want in two lines of code:

```cs
// using SimpleInjector;
// using SimpleInjector.Extensions;

var container = new Container();

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    assembly);

container.RegisterSingleDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(FactoryCommandHandler<>));
```

These two simple lines ensure the following:

- The supplied assembly is searched for concrete implementations of `ICommandHandler<T>`.
- If a concrete implementations has defines the `ICommandHandler<T>` interface multiple times, it is registered for each closed-generic version of that interface.
- The `FactoryCommandHandler<T>` is registered to be wrapped around `ICommandHandler<T>` implementations. For each closed-generic version of `ICommandHandler<T>` a single instance of that generic `FactoryCommandHandler<T>` is returned.
- A `Func<ICommandHandler<T>>` is injected into that `FactoryCommandHandler<T>` that allows creating the decoratee (the instance that is wrapped). This effectively delays the creation of that instance.
- The injected factory will preserve the lifestyle of the decoratee.

The `FactoryCommandHandler<T>` only depends on a `Func<T>` which is a singleton. The `FactoryCommandHandler<T>` can therefore be registered itself as a singleton (what happens in the registration above). If it depends on dependencies of other lifestyles, it might be better to register it as *transient*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Autofac also supports automatic delegate based factories without the need to explicitly register them. However, the `RegisterSingleDecorator` method really is nice, because that fact that it is missing is the source for this convoluted solution in Autofac. When I decided to use Autofac some years ago it seemed to be the one with the cleanest and simplest registration syntax. But that really looks nice. I guess I will have a closer look at Simple Injector.

Comment: I do agree that Autofac has a really nice and well though API. Simple Injector however is designed especially for the types of architectures you are dealing with. That's why the registration is so easy in this case. For other scenarios, designs or architectures, Autofac might be a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

I used the code in Matt Davies answer and improved it a bit:

- It now handles command handlers correctly that implement other interfaces.
- It now handles command handlers correctly that implement `ICommandHandler<T>` multiple times.
- I improved on my original version by fixing the first parameter to `WithParameter`. Like this it now supports multiple constructor parameters on `FactoryCommandHandler<T>`.

The result looks like this:

```
public static class AutofacExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterGenericTypesWithFactoryDecorator(
        this ContainerBuilder builder, 
        IEnumerable<Type> relevantTypes, 
        Type factoryDecorator,
        Type implementedInterfaceGenericTypeDefinition)
    {
        var serviceName = implementedInterfaceGenericTypeDefinition.ToString();

        foreach (var implementationType in relevantTypes)
        {
            var implementedInterfaces =
                implementationType.GetGenericInterfaces(
                    implementedInterfaceGenericTypeDefinition);
            foreach (var implementedInterface in implementedInterfaces)
                builder.RegisterType(implementationType)
                       .Named(serviceName, implementedInterface);
        }

        builder.RegisterGeneric(factoryDecorator)
               .WithParameter(
                   (p, c) => IsSpecificFactoryParameter(p, implementedInterfaceGenericTypeDefinition), 
                   (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed(serviceName, p.ParameterType))
               .As(implementedInterfaceGenericTypeDefinition)
               .SingleInstance();
    }

    private static bool IsSpecificFactoryParameter(ParameterInfo p,
                                                   Type expectedFactoryResult)
    {
        var parameterType = p.ParameterType;
        if (!parameterType.IsGenericType ||
            parameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<>))
            return false;

        var actualFactoryResult = p.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()
                                                 .First();
        if (actualFactoryResult == expectedFactoryResult)
            return true;
        if (expectedFactoryResult.IsGenericTypeDefinition && 
            actualFactoryResult.IsGenericType)
            return expectedFactoryResult == 
                   actualFactoryResult.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        return false;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericInterfaces(
        this Type type, Type openGenericInterface)
    {
        return
            type.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(x => x.IsGenericType &&
                            x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericInterface);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var relevantTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
builder.RegisterGenericTypesWithFactoryDecorator(
    relevantTypes.Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler")), 
    typeof(FactoryCommandHandlerDecorator<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```